# How to manually iterate a for loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

I got the following for loop with nested while loops:

```
new_offset = 0
threshold = 600
limit = 20000

counter = 0

for query in all_queries:
    print('query: ', query)

    params = {"q": query, "license": "public", "imageType": "photo", "count": threshold}

    while new_offset <= threshold:
        print('Finding results for query: ', query)
        params["offset"] = new_offset

        response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
        response.raise_for_status()
        search_results = response.json()

        new_offset = search_results['nextOffset']

        time.sleep(1)

        while len(list(contentUrls)) < limit:
            for i in search_results['value']:
                contentUrls.append(i["contentUrl"])
                print('contentUrls length', len(contentUrls))
                original_query.append(search_results['queryContext']['originalQuery'])
                query_result_name.append(i['name'])
                query_name.append(query)
                query_date.append(i['datePublished'])
```

This is basically an image scraper. The first while loop checks of new offset is less than or equal to the threshold. That logic basically allows me to move to the next page in Bing searches.

The second while loop collects the URLs of the images to be downloaded. There can only be `limit` amount of URLs in the `contentURL` list.

My question is: How can I, after having `contentURLs` reach the `limit` have `for query in all_queries` skip to the next query?

Comment: What is the datatype of `all_queries`, a list[???]? You can add on top of `for query in all_queries` another counter that is subtracted when `while len(list(contentUrls)) < limit:` is over. The main concept here is that you need to establish your `pagination` in a way that you can keep track of the current page, and also how many pages you need to go over and repeat the process. So imagine that when you finish the last `query_data.append` you just subtract from the index len and repeat the process.

Comment: So do you want it to move to the next query when `new_offset` > `threshold`, or when list of `content_urls` is greater than the limit or when you have iterated through all of the `search_results`.  it might be easier to describe what you are trying to achieve rather

Comment: `when list of content_urls is greater than the limit `

Comment: So the while loop that counts the threshold and the new_offset is uneccessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could probably recommend a better solution if I knew more about what you are trying to achieve, however, the example below should work the way you described. It skips to the next query once the length `contentUrls` reaches the `limit`.

I should mention that this code doesn't change the `limit` or reset the `contentUrls` list so once it has completed the first outer loop it will probably just skip over the inner `while` loop on any further iterations because the list is already at the limit.

```py
new_offset = 0
threshold = 600
limit = 20000
counter = 0


for query in all_queries:
    print('query: ', query)
    params = {"q": query, "license": "public", "imageType": "photo", "count": threshold}
    print('Finding results for query: ', query)
    params["offset"] = new_offset
    response = requests.get(search_url, headers=headers, params=params)
    response.raise_for_status()
    search_results = response.json()
    new_offset = search_results['nextOffset']
    value_results = search_results['value']
    if new_offset >= threshold:
        break
    time.sleep(1)
    for i in range(min(limit, len(value_results))):
        result = value_results[i]
        contentUrls.append(result["contentUrl"])
        original_query.append(search_results['queryContext']['originalQuery'])
        query_result_name.append(result['name'])
        query_name.append(query)
        query_date.append(result['datePublished'])
        print('contentUrls length', len(contentUrls))
```

Comment: My goal is that, once the limit is reached, the `for query in all_queries` increments but the new URLs are appended to `contentUrls`.

Comment: Threshold is the limit of pages of search results to go through, offset flips to the next page.

Comment: What's with `search_results = response.json()["value"]`?

Comment: And this? `result = search_results[i]`

Comment: Sorry i didn't notice the new_offset was also from the search result.... I changed it @oo92